# How to work with Meteor's template helpers asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I have in my HTML file the following code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="hpanel">
    <div class="panel-heading">Total Views</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="stat-num">{{Views}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have in my JavaScript file the following code that query MongoDB:

```
var Views = function() {
  var usersViews = Tracks.find().fetch().map(function(x) {
    return x.count;
  });
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<usersViews.length; i++)
    sum += parseInt(usersViews[i]);
  return sum;
}

Template.Campaign.helpers{{
  "Views": function() {
    return Views();
  }
}
```

I noticed that when I use such template helpers this increases dramatically the time till my UI is loaded, meaning that querying the database has affect on the time that takes the UI to load.
In my browser I don't see anything for long time, and then suddenly the UI appears.

How can I use the template helpers asynchronously (or any other way that will help me) so they won't affect the loading time of the UI?

Thanks,
Chad

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you are following right patters and you are doing template-level subscription and not router-level. Once you have the subscribed data on the client you will be able to fetch it very fast. Also subscribe only to the data you need and don't fetch the whole collection.

What you want is to show a message to your user that the page is loading while the subscription is not ready and then show the data once you have it. So something like:

```
<template name="blogPost">
 <a href="/">Back</a>
 {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
   {{#with post}}
     <h3>{{title}}</h3>
     <p>{{content}}</p>
   {{/with}}
 {{else}}
    <p>Loading...</p>
 {{/if}}
</template>
```

You can replace 'Loading...' with an animation or anything you want.

The helper for that example is

```
Template.blogPost.helpers({
  post: function() {
    var postId = FlowRouter.getParam('postId');
    var post = Posts.findOne({_id: postId}) || {};
    return post;
  }
});
```

and your template-level subscription:

```
Template.blogPost.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
    var postId = FlowRouter.getParam('postId');
    self.subscribe('singlePost', postId);  
  });
});
```

This example is from the documentation [here](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/subscriptions-and-data-management/with-blaze). For this example I have used FlowRouter, but the same applies to other routers as well.